# How to disable button OnClick when drag on the screen with OnMouseDrag in Unity

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, mouse, drag

I'm using `OnMouseDrag()` to change the camera view of the object on the screen. The code is like:

```
void OnMouseDrag() {    
if (isGameOver) {           
return;         
}       
float rotSpeed = GameConst.rotateSpeed * 20.0f ;
float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
float rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, -rotX);      transform.RotateAround(Vector3.right - Vector3.forward, -rotY);
}
```

Then I use `button.OnClick().AddListerner()` to attach a function when the button is clicked.

The problem is, everytime when I finish the drag, if the mouse up position is in the button region, the button would call the `OnClick()` function too. How can I disable `OnClick()` when it's a just a drag action?

Comment: Don't add listeners directly from your code for a simple click on a button. Assign that function directly from the inspector. It makes your code less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Wholeheartedly disagree. If there is no code to indicate a listener I'd say thats pretty hard to read. Inspector assignments are so fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the IDragHandler to perform the drag and set a flag that you have been dragging.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html

Then use the IPointerUpHandler to call the action if the flag is not on. Also, reset the flag whatever happened:

```
public class DragMe : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private bool isDragging = false;


    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        this.isDragging = true;
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
       if(this.isDragging == false){ Invoke();}
       this.isDragging = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems good to me. I set `isDragging = true` in `OnBeginDrag()` and set `isDragging = false` in `OnEndDrag()`. Check the `isDragging` in `OnClick()` function of buttons. Everything looks great now. Let test it more then I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to solve the problem I guess you could just add a boolean `isDragging` which you set to true when you enter `OnMouseDrag` and false when OnMouseUp. And then you wrap your buttons listener method with `if (!isDragging)` or equivalent.

There might be a more technical solution based on the behaviour of MonoBehaviour that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Not working, I guess the `OnClick()` executes after the `OnMouseUp()`.

Comment: Hm, resonable. You could solve it by delaying the bool switch with a Coroutine but that's pretty bad and is just asking for bugs. I'd probably change the button behavior to trigger only if OnMouseDown- and Up were on the button. I'm going to think about it for a few minutes...